# Create Custom NuGet Package In Visual Studio 2017

Tags: customization, nuget-package, pack, visual-studio-2017

I'm trying to create a custom package by VS2017, but so far without success. I am trying to add some .txt files to the root of the package, but it is not working.

**Structure of the Solution:**

```
ClassLibrary1.csproj
---> NugetContentFolder/Example1.txt
```

**Desired structure (Nuget):**

```
ClassLibray1.dll
Example1.txt
```

**I'm try:**

Build -> Pack ClassLibrary1

**XML:**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard1.6;net45</TargetFrameworks>
    <Authors>A</Authors>
    <Company>B</Company>
    <Product>C</Product>
    <Copyright>E</Copyright>
    <PackageLicenseUrl>F</PackageLicenseUrl>
    <PackageProjectUrl>G</PackageProjectUrl>
    <PackageIconUrl>H</PackageIconUrl>
    <RepositoryUrl>I</RepositoryUrl>
    <RepositoryType>J</RepositoryType>
    <PackageTags>L</PackageTags>
    <PackageReleaseNotes>M</PackageReleaseNotes>
    <NeutralLanguage>en-US</NeutralLanguage>
    <Description>H</Description>
    <files>
      <file src="Folder1/Example1.txt" target="Example1.txt" />
    </files>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'netstandard1.6' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.2-beta2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyModel" Version="1.0.1-beta-003206" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Runtime.Loader" Version="4.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.Extensions" Version="4.3.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Reflection.TypeExtensions" Version="4.3.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup Condition=" '$(TargetFramework)' == 'net45' ">
    <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="9.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" Version="3.0.0" />
    <Reference Include="System" />
    <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

How can I do this?

Finally, I found it very bad to couple this information inside 'csproj', it does not seem to me difficult to separate into another file.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: No, I change my nuget package

Comment: This link may be useful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets It contains some solution for the problem, but I didn't test them.

Answer (score 2):

What did work for me was adding the following section:

```xml
  <ItemGroup>
    <Content Include="..\..\LICENSE.txt" Link="LICENSE.txt">
      <PackagePath>LICENSE.txt</PackagePath>
      <IncludeInPackage>true</IncludeInPackage>
    </Content>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Edit: I found another solution which is simpler and prevents adding the files to the project:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="..\..\nuspec\install.ps1" Pack="true" PackagePath="tools" />
  <None Include="..\..\LICENSE.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
  <None Include="..\..\CHANGELOG.md" Pack="true" PackagePath="" />
  <None Include="..\libs\Interop\3.5\Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\net35" />
  <None Include="..\libs\Interop\4.0\Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\net40" />
  <None Include="..\libs\Interop\4.5\Interop.UIAutomationClient.dll" Pack="true" PackagePath="lib\net45" />
</ItemGroup>
```